# NodeJS - controller method not calling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a NodeJS application with port 7777.

`server.js`

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    router = require('./router');
var app = express();
var port = 7777;
app.use(router());
app.listen(port);
console.log('Doctor appointment at ' + port);
```

I am calling router from server and executng application as `node server.js`

`router.js`

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var doctorAppointment = require('./controllers/doctorAppointment');
module.exports = function() {
    var options = {
        caseSensitive: true
    };
    console.log("Router");
    // Instantiate an isolated express Router instance
    var router = express.Router(options);
    router.post('/appointment', doctorAppointment.takeAppoiment);
    return router;
}
```

I am calling controller method from router. Controller follows:

`doctorAppointment.js`

```
'use strict';

exports.takeAppoiment = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Inside appointment");
}
```

After execution, controller method is not calling

`system@DT-LNX-315:~/Desktop/nodeJS/doctor-appointment$ node server.js`
`Router`
`Doctor appointment at 7777`

And end point defined in http://localhost:7777/

coming as `Cannot GET /` in browser

And for http://localhost:7777/appointment

showing as `Cannot GET /appointment`. How to execute controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handling POST requests to `/appointment` with this line of code:

`router.post('/appointment', doctorAppointment.takeAppointment);`

Change `post` to `get` if you need just to access the page, like so:

`router.get('/appointment', doctorAppointment.takeAppointment);`

Also you don't have a handler for the index page, that's why you are getting the error for `/` path. You can add the handler the similar way:

`router.get('/', indexHandler);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Cannot GET /` in browser showing after execution. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

please use

```
app.get('/appointment',function(req,res){
   doctorAppointment.takeAppoiment();
})
```

in router.js

Comment: @zaynetro yes you can pass but i was just trying to give the idea.

Comment: Please tel where can I use post, get. If any more?

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao 'get' request means data you are sending to server will be sent in url which will be bad in case of sending sensitive data.

Comment: Doesn't mean necessarily that stuff will get sent in URL if you use GET. It might, if you use path variables or query parameters, but you can also send data in body, headers, etc. But it is kinda true that it's not as safe as POST though, that one is pretty easy to research/google.