# Why Node JS is not calling the service method from the controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am working on a Node JS project where my app has the following folder structure:

```
src
│   index.js        # Entry point for application
└───config          # Application environment variables and secrets
└───controllers     # Express controllers for routes, respond to client requests, call services
└───interfaces      # Interfaces for Database models
└───middlewares     # Operations that check or maniuplate request prior to controller utilizing
└───models          # Database models
└───routes          # Express routes that define API structure
└───services        # Encapsulates all business logic
```

What the issue is whenever I am trying to invoke a method present in service file it's skipping the line after coming to it and going inside catch. Below is the code of my controller & service:

**admin.controller.ts**

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import ERROR_TYPES from '../config/error';
import db from '../models';
import { AdminService } from '../services/admin.service';

export class AdminController {

    adminService = new AdminService();
    constructor() {
        dotenv.config();
    }

    async updateAdminUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
            console.log('a')
            let x = await this.adminService.updateAdminUserImpl(req.body, req.params.id); // By debugging I saw it's coming to this line and then going inside the catch block and not giving any error message
            console.log(x);
            res.status(ERROR_TYPES.UPDATED_SUCESSFULLY.code).send({ success: true, data: '', message: ERROR_TYPES.UPDATED_SUCESSFULLY.message, status: ERROR_TYPES.UPDATED_SUCESSFULLY.status });
        } catch(error) {
            res.status(ERROR_TYPES.SERVER_ERROR.code).send({ success: false, data: '', message: error, status: ERROR_TYPES.SERVER_ERROR.status });
        }
    }
}
```

**admin.service.ts**

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { AdminUserI } from '../interfaces/admin_user.interface';
import db from '../models';

export class AdminService {

    constructor() {
        dotenv.config();
    }

    private Validator(data: AdminUserI): boolean {
        console.log(data);
        return false;
    }

    async updateAdminUserImpl(req: any, id: string) {
        console.log(req);
        if(this.Validator(req)) {
            try {
                await db.AdminUser.update(req, { where: { id: id } });
                return { success: true, data: '', message: 'xyz' };
            } catch(error) {
                return { success: true, data: '', message: error };
            }
        } else {
            return { success: true, data: '', message: 'def' };
        }
    }
}
```

I am not understanding from where it's stopping. I followed some blogs like [this one](https://sodocumentation.net/node-js/topic/10785/route-controller-service-structure-for-expressjs) but still can't figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611830/nodejs-controller-method-not-calling
Hope This might help you.

Comment: nope this didn't helped much 

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the whole request to the function whose input type is declared as AdminUserI.

```
if(this.Validator(req))
```

and

```
private Validator(data: AdminUserI)
```

Comment: I'm not passing the whole request rather am passing the ```req.body``` only which is written in the **controller**